# Automatic hyphenation not working despite no conflict in parent css

Tags: css, deployment

I am attempting to auto hyphenate words should they extend past the allowed width, my understanding based on a few [sources](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/) is that with auto hyphen, words can be broken at appropriate hyphenation points either as determined by hyphenation characters inside the word however mine is not working.

```
.myText {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  line-height: 1 !important;
  max-width: 320px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
  hyphens: auto !important;
}
```

the word does break correctly, but does not add a hyphen to the end.

What i have done in an attempt to solve this issue is using

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
```

and investigating parent elements to see if they have specific overflow rules that override the ones i gave .myText (they do not)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic hypenation relies on the `lang` attribute being set. The source you referenced is out of date. The quote below is from the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens):

> Hyphenation rules are language-specific. In HTML, the language is
> determined by the lang attribute, and browsers will hyphenate only if
> this attribute is present and the appropriate hyphenation dictionary
> is available.

It will be easier to test this snippet if you use the **full page** link after you run it.

```css
article p {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<article lang="en">
  <p>The bowl was filled with fruit. It seemed to be an overabundance of strawberries, but it also included blueberries, raspberries, grapes, and banana slices. This was the meal Sarah had every morning to start her day since she could remember. Why she decided to add chocolate as an option today was still a bit of a surprise, but she had been in the process of deciding she wanted to change her routine. This was a baby step to begin that start.</p>
  <p>Benny was tired. Not the normal every day tired from a hard day o work. The exhausted type of tired where you're surprised your body can even move. All he wanted to do was sit in front of the TV, put his feet up on the coffee table, and drink a beer. The only issue was that he had forgotten where he lived.</p>
  <p>The choice was red, green, or blue. It didn't seem like an important choice when he was making it, but it was a choice nonetheless. Had he known the consequences at that time, he would likely have considered the choice a bit longer. In the end, he didn't and ended up choosing blue.</p>
  <p>Why do Americans have so many different types of towels? We have beach towels, hand towels, bath towels, dish towels, camping towels, quick-dry towels, and let’s not forget paper towels. Would 1 type of towel work for each of these things? Let’s take a beach towel. It can be used to dry your hands and body with no difficulty. A beach towel could be used to dry dishes. Just think how many dishes you could dry with one beach towel. I’ve used a beach towel with no adverse effects while camping. If you buy a thin beach towel it can dry quickly too. I’d probably cut up a beach towel to wipe down counters or for cleaning other items, but a full beach towel could be used too. Is having so many types of towels an extravagant luxury that Americans enjoy or is it necessary? I’d say it's overkill and we could cut down on the many types of towels that manufacturers deem necessary.</p>
  <p>The piano sat silently in the corner of the room. Nobody could remember the last time it had been played. The little girl walked up to it and hit a few of the keys. The sound of the piano rang throughout the house for the first time in years. In the upstairs room, confined to her bed, the owner of the house had tears in her eyes.</p>
</article>
```